# Create this effect on titanium scroll view elements

Tags: javascript, android, ios, scrollview, appcelerator-titanium

I have seen this in an some applications.

In this image there is an area with the letter A. When I scroll up the label moves up til it hits the top.  Then it stays there and the rest of the text scrolls under the label with the letter A.
Then comes a label with the letter B and it scrolls up till it hits the label A.  When this happens the label A moves up and is replaced by the label B.

[image: Label A in the home position]

[image: label A hase reached the top]

[image: label B hase reached label A]

[image: label B pushes label A up]

[image: label B hase replaced label A]

How can I create this effect in appcelerator studio with JavaScrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a TableView by using sections. Take a look at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView which explains how to do this.

Comment: You need to modify you data source array to have it sorted by name or some other Param you want displayed, then in each sections Header, label it as A or B depending on the first letter of each label to be displayed.  Another, easier way, is slice the first letter of each label, then use underscoreJS's groupBy method.

Comment: I have tried the example that is in the documentation and on iOS t works like expected but on Android it doesn't. The TableView reacts like a normal ScrollView. How can I make it work on Android?